# Scala conditionals and logicals over several Columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a Column with value based on several other columns:

```
val zzz = sc.parallelize(Seq(("2016-06-23", "VFF", "NO"), ("2016-06-23", 
null, "NO"), ("2016-01-23", "VFF", "NO"), ("2016-01-23", null, "NO")))
.toDF("last_ts", "fa_disposition", "vfir_scrap")

val newCol = when(to_date(col("last_ts")) >= "2016-06-01" && 
 col("fa_disposition").isNull(), 1)
.when(col("fa_disposition")=="VFF" && col("vfir_scrap")=="NO", -1)
.otherwise(0);    

val hdd3=zzz.withColumn("failure", newCol)
```

However, I get an error:

```
> error: type mismatch;
  found   : Boolean
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
           .when(col("fa_disposition")=="VFF" && col("vfir_scrap")=="NO", -1)
```

I tried searching, and looking through docs for Column, when, etc, and I don't understand this. 
Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and especially read [MCVE] as it will help you post questions that get the answers you seek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to replace `==` with `===` (equality for columns) and `isNull()` with `isNull` :

```
val zzz = sc.parallelize(Seq(("2016-06-23", "VFF", "NO"), ("2016-06-23", 
null, "NO"), ("2016-01-23", "VFF", "NO"), ("2016-01-23", null, "NO")))
.toDF("last_ts", "fa_disposition", "vfir_scrap")

val newCol = when(to_date(col("last_ts")) >= lit("2016-06-01") && 
 col("fa_disposition").isNull, 1)
.when(col("fa_disposition")==="VFF" && col("vfir_scrap")==="NO", -1)
.otherwise(0);    

val hdd3=zzz.withColumn("failure", newCol)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Column`'s [equal](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@===(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), not Scala's equal:

```
.when(col("fa_disposition")==="VFF" && col("vfir_scrap")==="NO", -1)
```

Comment: I tried that, and got a    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.apply(Column.scala:217)
  ... 48 elided

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using `udf` functions. `Udf` function require data serialization and deserialization and is **not recommended** to use when an `SQL functions` can suffice the solution. so @Raphael Roth answer is an ideal one for this case.

**This solution is only for knowledge base that above solution can be done using udf functions as well**

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val zzz = sc.parallelize(Seq(("2016-06-23", "VFF", "NO"), ("2016-06-23",
  null, "NO"), ("2016-01-23", "VFF", "NO"), ("2016-01-23", null, "NO")))
  .toDF("last_ts", "fa_disposition", "vfir_scrap")

def failure = udf((last_ts: String, fa_disposition: String, vfir_scrap: String) => {
  if((last_ts > "2016-06-01") && fa_disposition == null) 1
  else if((fa_disposition == "VFF") && vfir_scrap == "NO") -1
  else 0
})

val hdd3 = zzz.withColumn("failure", failure($"last_ts", $"fa_disposition", $"vfir_scrap"))
```